# Relay mutation is not resolving synchronously in test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have the following code essentially.

```
// MyComponent.js
const myMutation = graphql`
  mutation myMutation($input: MyInput!) {
    doMyMutation(input: $input) {
      ok
    }
  }
`

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [mutate] = useMutation(myMutation)
  const handleClick = async () => {
    const variables = {
      input: {
        stuff: true
      }
    }
    await mutate({ variables })
    myfunction('Hello World')
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
}

export default MyComponent

// test.js
import myfunction from './myfunction'

it('should finish mutation', async () => {
  environment.mock.queueOperationResolver(operation =>
    MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation)
  )

  const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />)

  fireEvent.click(getByText('Click Me'))

  expect(myfunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello World')
  // expect(AsyncRequestStore.clickToCall).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
})

// myfunction.js
const myfunction = (message) => {
  console.log(message)
}

export default myfunction
```

However, when I run the test, the mutation finishes after the test runs, saying there is something async going on. There are non timers I can see directly in my code. What could be causing this to not resolve the mutation until several frames/milliseconds later?

I would expect `myfunction` (which is mocked with `jest.mock('./myfunction')` to be called with `Hello World`, but it is not being called by the time at this point in the test, it only gets called after the test is done.

Comment: Please also add the text of the error that you are getting so we can help you.